# java - Hibernate Search - Unable to perform work. Entity Class is not @Indexed nor hosts @ContainedIn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I have a Spring JPA project with 3 entities: Author, Book and Category.

I want to use Hibernate Search for indexes.
Author class is @Indexed; Book class contains a Category field annotated with @ContainedIn; Category is a very simple class.

CLASS Author

```
@Entity
@Table
@Indexed
public class Author extends ConcreteEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

CLASS Book

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Book extends ConcreteEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ContainedIn
    private Category category;
}
```

CLASS Category

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Category extends ConceptEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

CLASS ConcreteEntity and ConceptEntity are similars:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ConcreteEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String value;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ConceptEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String value;
}
```

I've got this exception while saving a resource using Hibernate Search.

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to perform work. Entity Class is not @Indexed nor hosts @ContainedIn: class test.hibernate.search.Category
```

I don't understand how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Book is not configured correctly. You tell Hibernate Search that Book is included in the Category index (via your @ContainedIn annotation on the category field) but your Category entity is neither marked with @Indexed nor linked to another index via @ContainedIn.

Hibernate Search is just telling you that your configuration doesn't make much sense.

Considering your model, I'm pretty sure you wanted to mark category with @IndexedEmbedded instead.